# How can I multiply two polynomials in Python using a loop and by calling another function?

Tags: python, class, loops, polynomial-math, multiplication

I've been working at this problem for a couple hours now, but I don't know where to start or do anything. I understand the math/logic behind it, but I don't know to put it into code very well.

This is the problem:

1. Write and test a function *multiply(self, other)* that returns the product of two polynomials. Use one loop(for or while); within it call *multiply_by_one_term* from a previous question.

This is what I have set up in the beginning, I can't recall what it's called:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, coeffs=[0]):
        self.coeffs = coeffs
```

This is the test I have made:

```
def multiply(self, other):
    """
      >>> p1 = Polynomial([1, 2])
      >>> p2 = Polynomial([3, 4])
      >>> p1.multiply(p2).coeffs
      [3, 10, 8]
    """
```

This is the function I need to call:

```
def multiply_by_one_term(self, a, exp):
    """       
      >>> p = Polynomial([2, 1, 3])
      >>> p.multiply_by_one_term(3, 2).coeffs
      [6, 3, 9, 0, 0]
      >>> p = Polynomial([2, 1, 3])
      >>> p.multiply_by_one_term(3, 0).coeffs
      [6, 3, 9]
    """

    return Polynomial([a*i for i in self.coeffs] + [0]*exp)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. I'm still a noob when it comes to programming and I don't know it very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematically, the amount of coefficients we'll have in the end (or the power) should be the power of the first polynomial plus the power of the second, so we generate a list of that many zeroes. Now we iterate through the coefficients of the first polynomial. Here I'm using enumerate to keep track of which index we're currently on. This is of course assuming that the power each number is the coefficient of is the same as its index. So the number in item 2 will be before x^2.

For each coefficient of polynomial one, we loop through all of the coefficients of polynomial two (every coefficient of polynomial two needs to be multiplied with every coefficient of polynomial one). The resulting power will be the addition of the indices, which is taken care of with `final_coeffs[ind1 + ind2] += coef1 * coef2`. Then all that's left is to return the new Polynomial object.

Realize that here p1 and p2 are two Polynomial objects.

```
def multiply(p1, p2):
    final_coeffs = [0] * (len(p2.coeffs)+len(p1.coeffs)-1)
    for ind1, coef1 in enumerate(p1.coeffs):
        for ind2, coef2 in enumerate(p2.coeffs):
            final_coeffs[ind1 + ind2] += coef1 * coef2
    return Polynomial(final_coeffs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I just tried this and I get an extra 0 at the end.

Comment: @parmvirchahal Sorry, I'm not currently on a device with Python, so the code I posted is untested. Which end is the zero on (right or left)?

Comment: Ahh, you're right, that was a stupid mistake on my part. +1, good catch. This is a simple fix, I just forgot to add a minus one when making the final_coeffs list.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. I would vote up, but I have no reputation. And, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is an assignment because of the specific constraints.

The method of multiplication that I learned was a sum much like this:

```
12*34 = 12*30+12*4
```

For polynomials, we convert it to this:

```
(x+2)(3x+4) = (x+2)(3x)+(x+2)4
```

This translates readily to adding all results of

```
p1.multiply_by_one_term(p2.coeffs[i], len(p2.coeffs[i])-i-1)
```

Which means you need something like this:

```
# WARNING: This is not very idiomatic Python, but I can't think of a way to do it without indexes.
def multiply(self, other):
    subproducts = []
    for i in len(other.coeffs):
        subproducts.append(self.multiply_by_one_term(other.coeffs[i], len(other.coeffs)-i-1))
    add_subproducts_together(subproducts)
```

There should be some easy way to add the subproducts together as well. If not, you can write it by adding each of the like terms (remember that you need to align from the right).

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i did:

```
def multiple_polynoms(a,b):
len_a=len(a)
len_b=len(b)
mult=[]
mult_dict={}
mult_len= len_a+len_b-1
for i in range(mult_len):
    mult.append(0.0)
for i in range(len_a):
    for c in range(len_b):
        multi=a[i]*b[c]
        place=i+c
        if place in mult_dict:
            mult_dict[place]+=multi
        else:
            mult_dict[place]=multi
for t in mult_dict:
    mult[t]= mult_dict[t]
return mult
```